# Override PHPFox non-core modules/installed apps

Tags: phpfox

I would like to override a non-core module of PHPFox,so basically, it is an installed 3rd party application developed by PHPFox themeselves. Here is the file I would like to override.

> PF.Site/Apps/core-comments/views/block/comment.html.php

Anyway, I was able to override core modules in my theme following the naming convention from their documentation like the Feeds Module.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you'd like to override above file with the file in your module?
In the library, at step render template file, there is a hook. You can use this hook in your module and change above the to the file you want.

Comment: What library are you referring?